# How to write xpath in selenium webdriver for below HTML expressions?

Tags: selenium

I wrote `xpath` for below HTML code i.e. displayed below

```
1.   //a[@text()='Life Insurance']
2.  //span[@text()='Apply now']
```

But I got element not found exception. If I used Absolute xpath processor then It's working and I wrote own xpath then it thrown exception. 
Please tell me how to write it.

Below are the HTML code for which I need `xpath`.

```
1.<a class="mainlink" href="https://leads.hdfcbank.com/applications/webforms/apply/HDFC_Life_Click2Protect/index.aspx?promocode=P4_hp_AppNow_LI" target="" rel="nofollow width=375 height=213">Life Insurance</a> 

2." <div class="menutext"> <span class="mainlink">Apply now</span> <img class="pointer" alt="Pointer" src="/assets/images/nav_pointer.png" style="display: none;"> </div> "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these 
For 1

> //a[text()='Life Insurance']

For 2

> //span[text()='Apply now']

Comment: I tried it in few online xpath validator it was working :( http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html.

Comment: also I tried in this http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester ...maybe you're using it with more complex html ..so its better try directly in these websites

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine. But I got "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 181 milliseconds" error sometimes. and please can you tell me, as per convention we should write xpath like (//HTMLtagname[@attribute name= 'value'] ) but above code is working without "@". How?

Comment: @ represents attribute in XPath see here for more details http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathattribute.php

Comment: I know @ represent attribute but this code  " //a[text()='Life Insurance'] " is working without having @representation against attribute. Just tell me how   //a[text()='Life Insurance'] is worked.

Comment: I don't think Life Insurance is taken as attribute of anchor tag it is the text value.For example if you add id in your html
`<a class="mainlink" href="https://leads.hdfcbank.com/applications/webforms/apply/HDFC_Life_Click2Protect/index.aspx?promocode=P4_hp_AppNow_LI" target="" rel="nofollow width=375 height=213" id="3">Life Insurance</a> `
and now if you try //a[@id='3'] it will work

Comment: Ok fine. but I getting exception i.e. Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 296 milliseconds.

Comment: Just put a wait before executing that line if its still not visible and if it gives the same error after that then try to put your html the whole one in some xpath validator and check your xpath value.

Comment: I hv already put 5ms wait but still getting same exception. Ok try to check its value . Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove '@' in your code.
(or)

You can also use:

```
 //a[contains(text(),'Life Insurance')]
```

For 2

```
  //span[contains(text(),'Apply now')]
```